# How to type bengali vowel signs such as ‍ো, ‍ে in linux Bengali keyboard

Tags: linux, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I just want to write in Bengali by linux Bengali keyboard layout. I've found most characters but some characters seems to be missing. I don't know how to get these.

**Problem Description:**

I used to write something like story in my past windows pc's MS Office. But I've shifted to GNU/linux (ubuntu). So I decided to do the same thing in GNU/Linux's LibreOffice. But I fetched that there's a problem with Bengali keyboard. Because in my windows pc, there were some program like **Bijoy Bayanna**, **Avro**, **Bijoy 2000** etc to write in Bengali and well documentation about how to get some character that's not available directly. e.g., if I needed a character i.e. `ঔ`, I'd to type `g+X` particularly each of these keys hold `g holds for: ৲` and `X holds for : ৗ` and compositely these characters generate that I wanted character `ঔ`. But I couldn't find `৲` character in linux keyboard layout for Bengali fonts. If i'd, I wish that might work.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have all characters on the keyboard: you know you can get it alternative by holding the `ALT key` and typing its ASCII value?

Take a look at this site: [Unicode Entity Codes for the Bengali (Bangla) Script](http://symbolcodes.tlt.psu.edu/bylanguage/bengalichart.html)

As you see, there are the ASCII codes for all possible characters.
So you can type for example `অ` by holding the `ALT key` and typing `2437` and so on.

Comment: I've expanded my question's summary. Please review it and help me if you could.

Comment: No, why? I thought I had already?

Comment: You've done a lot for me. Reading your solution, I've got the idea. But unfortunately your method doesn't work under GNU/Linux machine. I've got it a little bit more useful (http://fsymbols.com/keyboard/linux/unicode/), through you gave me the base idea, thanks a lot. But you must know that it is not suitable to type 3-4 character by this method when these character's are very frequently used for. So if there's any solution like I've mentioned in **Problem Description:** section, it would be very appreciated. Anyway, Thanks for your special effort while nobody else did.